# Can’t access SceneKit assets in Playground

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I’m trying to access files in the art.scnassets folder. I’m using swift playgrounds so I put this folder in a `Contents/Chapter.playgroundchapter/PublicResources/art.scnassets/ship.scn`

I want to use this 3d model for ARKit but I can’t acess it using 
`let ship = SCNScene(name: “ship.scn”)`

I also tried `let ship = SCNScene(name: “PublicResources/art.scnassets/ship.scn”)`